# Creating loop of request

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Here is my code for making simple post request:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer=[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:Token forHTTPHeaderField:Authorization];
NSLog(@" Headers%@",manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", @"application/json", nil];
[manager POST:URLAdvanceSearch parameters:searchDictionary success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id root) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", root[@"data"]);
    if([[root valueForKey:@"isError"] boolValue]==0){
        NSLog(@"searchresult %@",root);
        //MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray=[root valueForKey:@"searchResult"];
        MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self compute:[root valueForKey:@"searchResult"] completionBlock:^(BOOL result){
            if(result){

                SearchResultVC.PinArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:pinArray];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:SearchResultVC animated:YES];
            }
        }];

    }
    else{
        [AJNotificationView showNoticeInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window type:AJNotificationTypeRed
                                       title:[root objectForKey:@"message"]
                             linedBackground:AJLinedBackgroundTypeDisabled
                                   hideAfter:GZAJNotificationDelay];
        return ;
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedFailureReason);
    if (operation.response.statusCode==401) {
        [MyAppDelegate LoginRequired:Nil];
        [MyAppDelegate ClearLoginData];
    }
    [AJNotificationView showNoticeInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window
                                    type:AJNotificationTypeRed
                                   title:error.localizedDescription
                         linedBackground:AJLinedBackgroundTypeDisabled
                               hideAfter:GZAJNotificationDelay];
    return ;
}];
```

Now I have put debug point in AFURLConnectionManager.h at this method:

```
 - (void)operationDidStart {
[self.lock lock];
if (![self isCancelled]) {
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    for (NSString *runLoopMode in self.runLoopModes) {
        [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:runLoop forMode:runLoopMode];
        [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:runLoop forMode:runLoopMode];
    }

    [self.connection start];
}
[self.lock unlock];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification object:self];
});

}
```

When I run my program it is going number of times in this loop I dont know why this is happening.From this request I am getting tabledata if my table data is 4 then it will goes in 4 times in this loop. If it is 3 then it will go 3 times. Now when I select any data from table and push any other view controller and when I simple return from that viewcontroller to tableview it is again going in this method though I am not making any request.

Comment: @Rob ....great rob.....i salute you....that is the only thing i forgot here....in table I am loading image with that class also....

Comment: @rob can you help me here to put mbprogrsshud in afnetworking class. I have create instance of MBProgressHUD in AFURLConncetionManager class...So it loaded number of times...So where to create instance of mbprogresshud to show only single time in table

Comment: I'd be inclined to have the view controller instantiate it. Perhaps this warrants its own question...

Comment: @Rob sorry I am not getting you...can you please expalin it

Comment: My point was simply that updating the UI in such a significant way that interrupts the UX in order to reflect that network requests are in progress doesn't strike me as the responsibility of some abstract network request class. I generally like my table's view controller, which initiated the request, to take responsibility for updating the UI (adding/removing HUD in your case). If you need greater clarity, I'd suggest you more fully explain your problem in a new question, and I, or others, can tackle it there. Discussing this in comments of this unrelated question doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making only one request, but seeing AFNetworking operations start multiple times, you might want to examine some of the properties here (notably `self.request`) to see what's getting requested multiple times.

I wonder if you have other AFNetworking calls that might have slipped your attention. Perhaps you  are you using AFNetworking's `UIImageView` category method, `setImageWithURL`, or something like that.